# Add a popup in a custom php webapp

Tags: php

I need to add a popup to the following web app

https://github.com/gunet/openeclass/tree/3.12.x

I have tried to put my code to many files by trial and error but no luck.

Could someone tell me if below code is the appropriate way to do this and in which file should i put it so it shows up in the first page?

https://openeclass.panteion.gr/

```
<?php
// PHP program to pop an alert
// message box on the screen
  
// Display the alert box 
echo '<script>alert("Welcome to our site")</script>';
```

?>

As suggested i plan to use the following. Where should i put it and how should i combine it with a cookie so that it is shown only once to each user?

```
<div class="modal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog">
  <div class="modal-dialog" role="document">
    <div class="modal-content">
      <div class="modal-header">
        <h5 class="modal-title">Modal title</h5>
        <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close">
          <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
        </button>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-body">
        <p>Modal body text goes here.</p>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-footer">
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary">Save changes</button>
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: The code is right. You need to put it in your index.php.

Comment: I have done it but the popup does not appear...https://github.com/gunet/openeclass/blob/3.12.x/index.php

Answer (score 0):

You should not use JavaScript "alert()" function to show some messages to the users. It is an ugly way to do such thing and it is mostly used for old school debugging helper.

In my opinion you can trigger a popover or an alert (see Bootstrap 3 documentation)  in `$(document).ready(function () { ... }` section within `template/default/js/main.js`. But this would show the message to your visitors every time they open any page. That is why you should show the message only once and remember it in a Cookie variable such as "messageShown=true". In the section which I mentioned above you should check like `if(Cookies.messageShown=='false')` before you trigger the alert message.

Comment: Could you please show me a full example? I have tried with bootstrap code for the popup and the corresponding html. Should i put both in main.js?

Comment: In my case i believe a popup modal in the center is ideal. (Bootstrap)

Comment: @vajabo I have never used openeclass before. I just navigated through the files on the github after I had read your question. It would take me too long time do provide you with a full example. But I can suggest some things. You should put the JavaScript logic into the documentReady section in the main.js inclusive the Cookie check. The html code for your model must be placed either in the main template or only in the template of your start page. You can check in main.js if user opened the start page (over location.href) for the first time(over cookie variable)